# I need to find out what the most popular sold product is within my data base, whilst showing the product ID, Name and Quantity sold

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

[Here is an image of my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTx2N.jpg)

[This is what my current code outputs when I enter it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAITx.jpg)

[This is what I need my code to be outputting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qc0F.jpg)

Comment: The out putted code show all products sold,  but I need it to show only the most sold product

Comment: Please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your code in the post itself, this will help those reading your question to better understand the nature of your problem and your current attempts to solve it.

Comment: Agreed with others. You should have put your code in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you just want the top record.
For starter, You can  append `LIMIT 1` at the end of the query. It should give you the top record.

You can also use [aggregation function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#:%7E:text=The%20BIT_AND()%20%2C%20BIT_OR(),maximum%20range%20of%2064%20bits.) MAX() for the quantity field to only choose the maximum one.

Answer (score -1):

If your select statement is working properly, I think you just need to add "limit 1" at the end of your statment.